# Why std::unary_function doesn't contain virtual destructor

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor

I came across class template `std::unary_function` and `std::binary_function`.

```
template <class Arg, class Result>
struct unary_function {
    typedef Arg argument_type;
    typedef Result result_type;
};

template <class Arg1, class Arg2, class Result>
struct binary_function {
    typedef Arg1 first_argument_type;
    typedef Arg2 second_argument_type;
    typedef Result result_type;
};
```

Both these can be used as base class for specific purposes. But still there's no virtual destructor in these. One reason which I could guess is these are not meant to be treated polymorphically. i.e

```
std::unary_function* ptr; 
//intialize it 
//do something
delete ptr;
```

But if that is so, shouldn't destructor be there with `protected` access specifier so that compiler would break any attempt to do that.

Comment: `protected` wouldn't allow you to create object with automatic storage (i.e on stack).

Comment: @Nawaz: well, you shouldn't have any need to create a `std::unary_function<A, R>` other than implicitly as a base of another object...

Comment: _"Both these can be used as base class for specific purposes."_ Could you elaborate about these proposed _purposes_?

Comment: You cannot use these classes polymorphically (there is no `operator()` to call). You are supposed to pass them by value and never allocate them on the heap. And they are deprecated anyway.

Comment: This templates have no virtual methods (and no non-virtual methods either), hence, they are useless as polymorphic bases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a well-balanced C++ design philosophy the idea of "preventing" something from happening is mostly applicable when there's a good chance of *accidental* and not-easily-detectable misuse. And even in that case the preventive measures are only applicable when they don't impose any significant penalties. The purpose of such classes as `unary_function`, `binary_function`, `iterator` etc. should be sufficiently clear to anyone who knows about them. It would take a completely clueless user to use them incorrectly.

In case of classes that implement the well-established idiom of "group member injection" through public inheritance, adding a *virtual* destructor to the  would be a major design error. Turning a non-polymorphic class into a polymorphic one is a major qualitative change. Paying such price for the ability to use this idiom would be prohibitively unacceptable.

A non-virtual protected destructor is a different story... I don't know why they didn't go that way. Maybe it just looked unnecessarily excessive to add a member function to that purpose alone (since otherwise, these classes contain only `typedef`s).

Note that even though `unary_function`, `binary_function` are deprecated, `iterator` is not. The deprecation does not target the idiom itself. The idiom is widely used within other larger-scale design approaches, like C++ implementation of *Mixins* and such.

Comment: A non-virtual protected destructor would make any derived class non-POD, which also arguably introduces pointless overhead in this context.

Comment: @Nemo: But the very use of inheritance already prevents the class from being an aggregate and, therefore, makes it non-POD.

Comment: Yeah, POD was an overstatement. I should have said "having a trivial destructor", which is also meaningful and useful for some optimizations.

Comment: @AndreyT Correct me if I am wrong, but POD does not have anything to do with aggregate. It is `standard-layout` + `trivial`. Since the base class would be empty in this case it is not a problem, isn't it?

Comment: @sbabbi: You are most likely right. I was referring to C++03 definition of POD. The definition has changed considerably in C++11. C++11 allows PODs with base classes.

Answer (score 3):

Because `std::unary_function` and `std::binary_function` are, by design, not supposed to be used for polymorphic deletion : they exist only to provide typedefs to the child classes, and have no other intent.

Being a base class in C++ does not mean that the class must exhibit any particular **polymorphic behaviour**.

i.e. you should never see code such as :

```
void foo(std::unary_function* f)
{
     delete f; // illegal
}
```

Note that both classes are **deprecated** since C++11 ([See N3145](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3145.html))

Answer (score 2):

The basic reason the various type tags (e.g., there is also `std::iterator<...>`) don't play nicely with people believing everything derived from is meant to be a base class is that overall design of STL where they are used frowns upon the use of inheritance for polymorphism. That is, the people who proposed these classes wouldn't see any reason why anybody would want to treat anything dynamically polymorphic, especially not any of these empty-by-design type tags. Thus, little effort was made to prevent silly mistakes.

When these classes were accepted as part of the STL at large there was a lot more effort spent on removing the rough edges of STL and not so much on unimportant details. Also, having the type tags being empty could be useful as they wouldn't interfere with some of the constraints place upon classes using any access specifiers. Thus, the type tags were left empty.

As it is specifically not needed to use any of these type traits with C++11 (the return type can be determined upon use and the arguments can be perfectly forwarded) these types are being deprecated rather than getting "fixed" (assuming they are considered broken).

Comment: That means standard left it ( as it doesn't seem to be under important things)even they could provide protected destructor for better safety.

Comment: @Ravi: Yes. It was quite deliberately not changed for C++11, e.g., because it was deprecated and it isn't broken: there is nothing wrong with the interface at all. It may catch out people who think they can get by without reading the documentation but this is considered added benefit by some.